# What was the Star Trek IMAX project?

Tags: star-trek

In [this interview](http://www.startrek.com/article/rick-berman-looks-back-at-18-years-of-trek-part-2) at the official Star Trek web site, *TNG*-era producer Rick Berman mentioned that while he and the Star Trek creative team were working on *Voyager*,

> ...there was an IMAX project that we developed but the studio ended up not being able to make a deal with the IMAX people. It was in the early days of IMAX. It was before movies were coming out in IMAX like they were today. But it was a great script and certainly something that would have been exciting to do.

**What was this shelved Star Trek IMAX project?  Which ship and/or crew would it have involved?  What details are known about the script?**

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_IMAX

Comment: @Richard I just looked at that; pretty much nothing extra there other than O'Brien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure all of your questions can be answered, but I've found some [very interesting information](http://web.archive.org/web/20090426070307/http://www.geocities.com/Hollywood/6952/imax.htm) to answer some of them:

- From Ian Spelling's "Sci-Fi" syndicated column: 
  Interview with Rick Berman (January 22 [I assume 1996): Miles O'Brien was going to be involved
- December 30 in *TV Guide*: It would be 40 minutes long and (of course) filmed in IMAX 3D with a draft supposed to be ready by early January 1997
- November 3 from *Star Trek Communicator*:

> What is happening on the IMAX movie?
>
> BERMAN: We've completed a story that was written by myself and Hans Tobeason.
>   I'm very pleased with it and Paramount is very pleased as well. It has
>   now gone off to IMAX. We're just waiting to see what the next step is
>   going to be.

This indicates to me that there is a script out there somewhere!

> Are you planning on featuring more than one Star Trek crew in this
>   IMAX film?
>
> BERMAN: At the moment, it features **one well-known Star Trek** **character** [probably O'Brien] and a
>   number of other actors who are not known. There is a good chance that
>   there will be some peripheral performances by other known Star Trek
>   characters.

- June 11 1997 *Star Trek Communicator*: it was intended to have some scientific/educational elements to it, but still predominately entertainment
- February 25 1997 *Star Trek Communicator*: it had a budget of $10 million

Based on the above information, it seems most likely that we were going to see a new ship and crew (with O'Brien aboard it).  The details other than this though seem to be awfully scant!